# How to execute a method in onDestroy?

Tags: java, android, ondestroy

I'm writing an android app using a server. When the user exit the activity (remove it from recent activities) I want to close the connection and do some modifications in the server side before destroying the activity. So I read about the activity life cycle and I found out that I need to write the last call for closing the connections in `onDestroy()`. So that what I did:

Main activity:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();
    try {
        ConnectionHandler.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Connection Handler:

```
public static void close() throws IOException {
    try {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        json.put("client", "close");

        mConnectionHandler.new AsyncSendToServer().execute(json.toString());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    socket.close();
}
```

The message transfer is working, but the activity does not execute the `ConnectionHandler.close()` method. What should I do to execute this method when the user close the activity?

Answer (score 1):

You have to write the `super.onDestroy` after your code.
Try:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    try {
        ConnectionHandler.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: OK I fixed some errors, but it sends null when using `onDestroy()`, and send json with "client" "close" string when calling it from another place, not from `onDestroy()`